# Ubuntu SSH connection to server | Open file with texteditor

Tags: server, ssh, 19.04, gedit

I have an SSH connection to my server.

I need to edit `/etc/turnserver.conf`.

I can access the file with `vi /etc/turnserver.conf`. But honestly thats the worst **** I have ever experienced in my career as a programmer.

I have tried to install gedit, which was successful:

```
sudo apt install gedit
```

Sadly using gedit to open the file does not work:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(org.gnome.gedit:22284): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:54:11.169: cannot open display:
```

It seems something is missing on the server. But I dont know what. 
I am using these commands as root.

I found a solution where someone proposed to install `gksudo` and run `gksudo gedit ...` but this did not work:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gksudo
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about `nano` ?

Comment: To use gedit remotely over SSH, you will need to invoke it with X forwarding (`ssh -X`). See for example [using gedit through ssh connection - should I have gedit installed on the server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70377/using-gedit-through-ssh-connection-should-i-have-gedit-installed-on-the-server). Alternatively there are other CLI editors that you may find easier than vi (such as `nano` for example)